# XML Parsing: Cannot Find Nodes by Tagname

Tags: java, xml

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<subscriber>
    <data name="quota">
        <![CDATA[
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><usage><version>1</version><field name="Cid"/><field name="Time"/><field name="totalVolume">4</field><field name="inputVolume"/><field name="outputVolume"/><field name="serviceSpecific"/><field name="nextResetTime"/><field name="Type"/><field name="GrantedTotalVolume"/><field name="GrantedInputVolume"/><field name="GrantedOutputVolume"/><field name="GrantedTime"/><field name="GrantedServiceSpecific"/><field name="QuotaState"/><field name="RefInstanceId"/><field name="Name">TEST_QUOTA</field></usage>
]]>
    </data>
</subscriber>
```

In order to find all the `field` nodes, I wrote:

```
dbuilder = dbc.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dbuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("field");
log.debug("node list length: " + nl.getLength());
for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength(); i++){
    Element e = (Element)nl.item(i);
    log.debug("node: " + e);
    String name = e.getAttribute("name");
}
```

However, the length of the `NodeList` is 0, so it cannot find any node with name `field`. I wonder if it's because of the meta data outside the `field` nodes, and if so, how can I access the `field` nodes?

Comment: did you extract the content of the data tag? Anything inside an <![CDATA[ region will not register as elements.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't. Should I `doc.getElementsByTagName("data")` first?

Comment: @k5_ if they don't register as elements, how can I parse them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to extract the data element from the initial document

```
    Document doc = dbuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
    Element subscriber = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("subscriber").item(0);
    Element data = (Element) subscriber.getElementsByTagName("data").item(0);
```

After that you need to use its TextContent to parse the document you actually want.

```
    Document doc2 = dbuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(data.getTextContent().trim())));
    Element usage = (Element) doc2.getElementsByTagName("usage").item(0);
    NodeList nl = usage.getElementsByTagName("field");
```